# Centered navbar with left logo

Tags: html, css, center, navbar, nav

I'm trying to have a centered navbar, with a logo floated to the left.

Here's a good example: http://www.bootply.com/98314

I want something similar to that example, but to instead swap the left-floated items with the Brand. I will keep the right-floated items there.

I currently have this: http://www.bootply.com/p6XOQQFZQT (don't worry about the not vertically aligned text)

As you can see, if you remove the floated-left element, the navbar centers, meaning that with the floated-left element included, the navbar is not truly centered on the page.

I think I need to have the navigation elements' position absolute so that they stick in the middle, but each time I do this it just removes the entire navbar background and you barely see the text.

I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6qcrevxe/

```
header {
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
}
.global-nav {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #205081;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #235990;
    position: relative;
}
.global-nav ul {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.global-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-link a {
    padding: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #235990;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it was something to do with absolute, just didn't know what!

Comment: Sorry to bug again, but how would you go about adding multiple right-floated elements to the bar? You can't have both of them be position: absolute; because then they'll just overlap each other.

Any tips?

Comment: @Sej I don't quite understand what the question is, but you can have multiple absolute elements without overlapping by set different left, right, top or bottom positions.